# Deserialize JSON object from reference ID in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a list of items in json

```
"items":[
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Thats a name",
        "type": 0,
        "price": 3.5,
        "ingredients": [1,0,2,3],
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "This is AnotherName",
        "type": 0,
        "price": 3.7,
        "ingredients": [5,0,6,10,2,8],
      }
]
```

The `type` and `ingredients` properties are detailed in another object of the same JSON file. If I look it up, I know what a type 0 is, and what the ingredients are.

What I'm trying to achieve, in c#, is to have my data model not having `int` everywhere, but having the actual objects. For example, with the ingredients, my `Item` object has an `Ingredients` property of type `List<Ingredient>` and **not** `List<int>`.

Like the following :

```
public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<FoodType> Types { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<FoodItem> Items { get; set; }


public class FoodItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

But in the current state of my deserialization, it crashes because it's looking for an int.

I've found keywords but not real help, about "PreserveReferenceHandling" or "isReference" but I'm not sure what those are and even less how to use them.

This is how I deserialize :

```
var json = r.ReadToEnd();
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EatupDataModel>(json);
```

I know the following would work :

- Change the json file to include actual objects and not ID's
- Change data model to use `int`'s and not objects

But I would *very* much like not to go that way, the first one requiring an insane amount of tedious work, and the other one forcing me to have 2 versions of pretty much the same objects, and then map the properties in between. That seems silly, surely I can't be the first person to face this.

What can I do to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Create a custom converter to parse the json and create the desired object model

Answer (score 2):

```
You will want to clean this up a bit. But should give you a proof of concept on how to do create your custom converter.

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KeysJsonConverter))]
    public List<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
public class KeysJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{      
    public KeysJsonConverter()
    {

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");

    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var ingredientsList = new List<Ingredient>();

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
                List<int> items = token.ToObject<List<int>>();
                ingredientsList = items.Select(x => IngredientList.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x)).ToList();
            }
        }
        return ingredientsList;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
   public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object[]);
    }
}
public static class IngredientList
{
    public static List<Ingredient> Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>()
    {
        new Ingredient()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Test 1"
        },
        new Ingredient()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Test 2"
        }
    };
}
public class Ingredient{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```